# Can I split a command over multiple lines in Apache Pig Latin?

Tags: apache-pig

I have some very long lines as Apache Pig (Latin) expressions. Is there a way of splitting these over multiple lines?

I've tried a trailing backslash to no avail, as soon as I press <kbd>enter</kbd> the (incomplete) command executes...

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing at a Pig 0.8 grunt shell and I just hit return and it gives me a continuation prompt ">>". It doesn't appear to have any problem splitting individual statements over multiple lines in interactive mode, which is what it sounded like you were asking about.  You can also feed a script with multiline statements to Pig via STDIN.

Answer (score -4):

I can't test it right now, but if memory serves me well, the underscore character "_" should help you splitting your command over multiple lines.

```
The beginning of my very very very very _
very very very very very very very very _
very very very long command
```

Comment: I tried it and in interactive mode it doesn't work. Perhaps it might work for scripts?

Comment: It's possible that there is no answer; maybe interactive mode doesn't support any line extension character.

Comment: just checked that this is not working for v0.15.0